# How to generate random number of garbage files of random size

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script that will generate a random number of garbage files of random length. Ideally 1-50 files of length 100Kb-100Mb. I have written this script but does only generate 2 files. I would also like the filename to be the string "RanDoM" followed by a random number.

What am i doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

ntimes=$(( ( RANDOM % 50 )  + 1 ))

for i in {1.. $ntimes}
do
   dd if=/dev/urandom of=$RANDOM bs=1K count=$(((RANDOM % 10000) + 1))
done
```

Comment: Use sparse files? `seq 50 | xargs -I XXX bash -c 'truncate -s ${RANDOM}b file.XXX'`

Answer (score 1):

The construct `{1..$var}` does not work because brace expansion happens before variable expansion. From the bash man page:

> ```
>    The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter
>    and  variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution
>    (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and pathname  expan-
>    sion.
> ```

You can get the functionality you want using an external tool like `seq`:

```
for i in $(seq 1 $ntimes); do
  dd ...
done
```